# combine multiple arrays from array object and pick out uniques

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code does what i want it to do. Which is to combine all of the unique `tags` arrays from `faqs[i].tags`... How can i re factor `setFaqTopics()` with better javascript?

```js
const faqs = [
 {
  tags: ['placing an order']
 },{
  tags: ['general']
 },{
  tags: ['placing an order']
 },{
  tags: ['general', 'dog']
 }
]

function setFaqTopics(faqs) {
 const tags = [];
 let tag_arrs = faqs.map( it=> {
  tags.push(it.tags[0])
  if (it.tags[1]) tags.push(it.tags[1])
  if (it.tags[2]) tags.push(it.tags[2])
  if (it.tags[3]) tags.push(it.tags[3])
  if (it.tags[4]) tags.push(it.tags[4])
  if (it.tags[5]) tags.push(it.tags[5])
 });
 return uniq(tags);
}

console.log(setFaqTopics(faqs))

function uniq(a) {
    return a.sort().filter(function(item, pos, ary) {
        return !pos || item != ary[pos - 1];
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added a better code below. Please take a look

```
const faqs = [
            {
                tags: ['placing an order']
            },{
                tags: ['general']
            },{
                tags: ['placing an order']
            },{
                tags: ['general', 'dog']
            }
        ]

        function setFaqTopics(faqs) {
            const tags = new Set();
            let tag_arrs = faqs.map( it => {
                it.tags.map(val => {
                  tags.add(val)
                });
            });
            return Arrays.from(tags).sort();
        }

        console.log(setFaqTopics(faqs))
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: better way to do the sorting.

Comment: Edited the answer with `Array.from(tags).sort()`